# org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE: vmcid: SUN minor code: 201 completed: No

Tags: java, corba

All,

I am attempting to follow a simple Java/Corba tutorial.

However, when attempting to start the Server.java program I always run into the following error:

WARNING: "IOP00410201: (COMM_FAILURE) Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: localhost; port: 900"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
.
.
.
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

I realize this has been posted before.  However, I am completely new to CORBA and am at a loss as to how to correct the error.

Here is the snippet, in Server.java, that is throwing the error:

org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");

I can start the ORBD by using this command: orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost

I can also start tnameserver by using this command: start tnameserv -ORBInitialPort 1051

However, that is as far as I understand about how to correct.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost -- starts without exception

start tnameserv -ORBInitialPort 1051 -- starts without exception

java Server ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost -- throws connection refused exception...

Comment: What version of Java?

Comment: Your Question would be easier to read if you formatted with the quotation, code, and other options provided in page editor.

Comment: java version "1.8.0_341"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_341-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.341-b10, mixed mode)

Comment: Here is the URL to the tutorial I am attempting to run: https://github.com/johnngugi/CORBA-Example.  I get as far as the step to start the server.

Comment: So, I've made some progress....  My original issue was that the 'orbd' was not running; hence the connection refused.  I neglected to prefix the command with 'start' because I am running Windows.  However, now I am getting 'permission denied' socket exception, which I cannot explain because I am on localhost..

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution!

I had to specifically start all three **objects**, **orbd**, **server** and **client** indicating to only use **IPV4**:

```
orbd -J-verbose -J-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -J-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost

java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false Server

java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=false Client -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost localhost
```